# Element floats on right side (even though float: left is set)

Tags: css, css-float

I'm lining up images besides each other with *float: left* which works fine until the next line. By some reason the image on the next line is positioned on the right side and the image after that on a new line to the left. It's hard to explain so it's better you see it yourself: http://spiritusmundi.se/om-oss/verksamhetsberattelse/

What could be the issue here?

Comment: try .post-container {
    display: block;
} and    .float-left {
    display: inline-block; remove float left
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try like this below :

```
.float-left { display: inline-block; 
    float left //remove this
    }
```

Check and let me know

Comment: Solved the problem! Thanks a lot!